# Python closures

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-3.3

```
def counter(x):

    def _cnt():
        #nonlocal x
        x = x+1
        print(x)
        return x

    return _cnt
a = counter(0)
print(a())
```

Above code gives the following error

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Why this is not able to create a new object with value 'x+1' in the namespace of _cnt and bind it to x. we will have reference x in both function namespaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you assign to a name in a given scope, all references to the same name inside the same scope are local. Hence `x + 1` cannot be evaluated (as it tries to reference the local `x`).

Hence this works:

```
def f():
    x = 42
    def g():
        print(x)
    g()
f()
```

But this doesn't:

```
def f():
    x = 42
    def g():
        print(x)
        x = 42
    g()
f()
```

---

The first `print` has this bytecode:

```
0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print) 
3 LOAD_DEREF               0 (x) 
6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 
9 POP_TOP
```

while the second `print` has this one:

```
0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print) 
3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x) 
6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 
9 POP_TOP
```

Comment: I think an assignment statement like 'x = x + 1' is executed like this. First expression x + 1 is evaluated (so x is refering to counter's x) and then the return value of the expression is assigned to x (this should create a new reference in _cnt's namespace

Comment: As you can see in my second example, as soon as you assign to a name, all reference to it become local, no matter if they happen before or after the assignment.

Comment: @user634615 I added the disassemblies. The `LOAD_FAST` is what fails.

Comment: it means the flow of assignment statment differs according to where it is used. That is  a bit surprising

Comment: @user634615: name locality is defined at *compile time*, not at execution time. Expression execution order has no influence on that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters then why above code works if x is mutable obect

Comment: @user634615: Because you are not changing the `x` name itself. It remains unchanged; it is bound to an object and only that *object* changes.

Answer (score 1):

The scopes of function `counter` and `_cnt` are not the same. Even though they're nested, it doesn't matter.

So the `x` in `counter` does not exist in `_cnt`. Perhaps pass it as an argument (or use `nonlocal`, as you seemed to have understood)