# Python scope when assignment never performed

Tags: python, scope

So I get that

```
x = 5
def f():
    print(x)

f()
print(x)
```

gives back 5 and 5.

I also get that

```
x = 5
def f():
    x = 7
    print(x)

f()
print(x)
```

gives back 7 and 5.

What is wrong with the following?

```
x = 5
def f():
    if False:
        x = 7   
        print(x)
    else:
        print(x)

f()
print(x)
```

I would guess that since the `x=7` never happens I should get 5 and 5 again. Instead I get

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

Does python regard `x` as a local variable because in this indented block there is an assignment expression regardless if it is executed or not? What is the rule exactly?

Comment: Python Scope is based on LEGB(Local, Enclosing, Global, and Built-in), there's plenty of articles explaining how it woks. Maybe start here: https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - reassigning a name inside a function that previously has been looked up in the global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231598/python-reassigning-a-name-inside-a-function-that-previously-has-been-looked-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the current block. This can lead to errors when a name is used within a block before it is bound. This rule is subtle. Python lacks declarations and allows name binding operations to occur anywhere within a code block. The local variables of a code block can be determined by scanning the entire text of the block for name binding operations.

Answer (score 4):

When the function is defined python interprets `x` as a local variable since it's assigned inside the body of the function. During runtime, when you go into the `else` clause, the interpreter looks for a **local variable** `x`, which is unassigned.

If you want both `x` to refer to the same variable, you can add `global x` inside the body of the function, before its assignment to essentially tell python *when I call `x` I'll be referring to the global-scope `x`*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `global` in your function `f()` like so:

```
x = 5
def f():
    global x
    if False:
        x = 7   
        print(x)
    else:
        print(x)

f()
print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know how to make it work with the global, I just want to know why on earth would python do this.

Comment: Check out the docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global-stmt or https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces